# Is it possible to infer a general type signature from a more specific type signature?

Tags: types

Given some type signatures like this:

```
type Foo = { name : String }

getFooName : Foo -> String

getName : { a | name : String } -> String
```

Is it possible to infer that `getName` can be used in place of `getFooName`?

Comment: You're possibly thinking of something along the lines of row polymorphism, see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53998/what-are-the-major-differences-between-row-polymorphism-and-subtyping) for a good discussion of the differences between structural subtyping, row polymorphism, and actual type judgements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is a working example in elm. You can run it at http://elm-lang.org/try

```
import Html exposing (text)

type alias Foo = { name : String }

fnThatUsesAGetFooName : ( Foo -> String ) -> Foo -> String
fnThatUsesAGetFooName x foo = x foo

getName : { a | name : String } -> String
getName v = v.name

arg: Foo
arg = { name = "gmorenz" }

main = 
  text (fnThatUsesAGetFooName getName arg)
```

This is known as "structural typing" (and I think "row typing").

You could also view this problem in a type system with interfaces or typeclasses like rust. Automatically create and implement "varname_with_type_typeid" traits (interfaces) with getters and setters for every field  in every structure. Obviously this requires extending the compiler, but since it's a simple textual transformation it is easy theoretically speaking. Then getName would look like

```
fn getName<T: name_with_type_TypeIdOfString>(input: T) -> String { 
    t.get_name_with_type_TypeIdOfString()
}
```

and you could make a `fn(Foo) -> String` out of it by saying `getName::<Foo>`.